# How to create a timeseries starting "2000-01-01" and 10 weekends(saturdays) after that having random numbers as values.(in Python)?

Tags: python, date, time, data-analysis, series

```
rnge = pd.date_range(start = "2000-01-01" ,periods =14 , freq = "D")
rnge
```

I want saturdays to be excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understood the question (didn't get the part about random numbers).
If you just want to filter out Saturdays then it can be done like this:

```
rnge = pd.date_range(start="2000-01-01", periods=14, freq="D")
rnge = rnge[rnge.weekday != 5]
```

Result:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04', '2000-01-05',
               '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07', '2000-01-09', '2000-01-10',
               '2000-01-11', '2000-01-12', '2000-01-13', '2000-01-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: can you elaborate the 2nd line of code

Answer (score 1):

```py
dates = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=10, freq='W-SAT')
# Create a list of random numbers
values = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=10)

df = pd.Series(values, index=dates)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
2000-01-01    7
2000-01-08    0
2000-01-15    8
2000-01-22    1
2000-01-29    5
2000-02-05    3
2000-02-12    8
2000-02-19    7
2000-02-26    8
2000-03-04    4
Freq: W-SAT, dtype: int64
```

'W-SAT' means every Saturday. You can check date_range function here.
[pandas.date_range — pandas 1.5.2 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)